# Django foreign key relationship with multiple models

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have many different models with different types of fields. I want to use foreign key for multiple models. Like:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    
class Model2(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uploadedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
class MainModel(models.Model):
    
    content = models.ForeignKey([Model1, Model2], on_delete=models.CASCADE) # this will give error
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

models.py

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey

class MainModel(models.Model):
    
    target_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
    related_name='target_obj', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_ct', 'target_id')
```

now from your main model you can access any model you want.
To use it let us say you have an instance like this.

```
model1 = Model1.objects.first()
```

to pass this to your MainModel you can just do something like this.

```
   MainModel.objects.create(target=model1)
```